# why loop is not working in my given method

Tags: java, loops, methods

I am trying to create a method by which if a wrong passkey is entered, then a loop will run saying invalid passkey and on the 3rd turn it will exit.
but loop is not working why i am creating it in a method.

```
import java.util.*;

import static java.lang.System.exit;

public class Main {

    public static void password(String passkey, int i) {
        while (i <= 3) {
            //Switch can be used too!
            i++;
            if (passkey.equals("TerrorX")) {
                System.out.println("Welcome Master Puneet \nI am really happy to see you here");
                exit(0);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                System.out.println("You have exceeded multiple attempts");
            } else if (!passkey.equals("TerrorX")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid Passphrase \n Kindly Try Again");
                exit(0);
            }


        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Self Taught AI");
        System.out.println("Creator Puneet Sharma");
        System.out.println("To Proceed further Please enter your passkey");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String passkey1 = input.next();
        // Taking Commands here
        password(passkey1,0);
    }
}
```

I was expecting a loop to run but it not, only while i created it in a method.

Comment: what is `exit(0)` expected to do, after the "...Try Again" message? [documentation of exit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)): "Initiates the shutdown sequence of the Java Virtual Machine. This method always blocks indefinitely."

Comment: You're only reading the input once, outside your loop. Your `password` method is also only ever running once.

Comment: `while (true) System.exit(0);` is not a loop for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not looping 3 times is because your 3rd condition contains an *exit* call.

```java
else if (!passkey.equals("TerrorX")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Passphrase \n Kindly Try Again");
    exit(0);
}
```

Thus, if I enter the wrong password, it will exit the program.

Furthermore, it will simply loop 3 times on an incorrect *passkey* value, and exit.
It will not have been provided with an updated user input.

```
Welcome to Self Taught AI
Creator Puneet Sharma
To Proceed further Please enter your passkey
abc
Invalid Passphrase 
 Kindly Try Again
Invalid Passphrase 
 Kindly Try Again
You have exceeded multiple attempts
Invalid Passphrase 
 Kindly Try Again
```

Here is how to resolve the issue.

Increase the scope of the *Scanner* object, and place it as a class variable.  So, outside of a method.
Additionally, it must be declared as *static*, since your method is static.

You can then access it from within the *password* method, in order to capture a new input value from the user.

On a final note, the *while-loop* conditional statement should be checking for an *i* value lesser-than *3*, and not equal-to it.

```
Welcome to Self Taught AI
Creator Puneet Sharma
To Proceed further Please enter your passkey
abc
Invalid Passphrase 
 Kindly Try Again
Please enter your passkey
abc
Invalid Passphrase 
 Kindly Try Again
Please enter your passkey
abc
You have exceeded multiple attempts
```

Here is the re-factored code.

```java
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void password(String passkey, int i) {
    while (i < 3) {
        //Switch can be used too!
        i++;
        if (passkey.equals("TerrorX")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome Master Puneet \nI am really happy to see you here");
            exit(0);
        } else if (i == 3) {
            System.out.println("You have exceeded multiple attempts");
        } else if (!passkey.equals("TerrorX")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Passphrase \n Kindly Try Again");
            System.out.println("Please enter your passkey");
            passkey = input.next();
        }


    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Self Taught AI");
    System.out.println("Creator Puneet Sharma");
    System.out.println("To Proceed further Please enter your passkey");

    String passkey1 = input.next();
    // Taking Commands here
    password(passkey1,0);
}
```